# What's wrong with my LinkedIn API call syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api, omniauth

I'm using omniauth to access profiles, though I've setup the linkedin gem and used the access tockens from omniauth so that I can do a seperate pull to access different picture sizes.

Here's my code:

```
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new
  client.authorize_from_access(auth.extra.access_token.token, auth.extra.access_token.secret)
  linkedinpicture = client.profile.picture-urls::(original)
```

This doesn't work, it returns an error of

```
undefined local variable or method 'urls'
```

But at the same time I know the API caller is working because if I access the users headline (client.profile.headline) instead of their picture-urls then it works fine. Is it something with the syntax that I need to format properly? I'm guessing it doesn't like the '-' character.

Here's the LinkedIn documentation I'm referencing: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: you should check the gem that provided the `LinkedIn` module

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
linkedinpicture = client.profile.picture-urls::(original)
```

Try:

```
linkedinpicture = client.picture_urls(:id => 'id_of_connection')
```

See https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin/blob/c0ec6a6960f21fcd428916c53b3c229907a7af79/lib/linked_in/api/people.rb#L56-L70 for the relevant gem code.